# axios returns promise instead of data

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am querying some data from IPFS using axios, the problem is that after calling the specific api the return value is a promisse from axios.

```
const getNFTDetail = async (url: string) => {
    const urlIPF = url.replace("ipfs://", "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/");
    try {
      return await axios.get(urlIPF).then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

response I get:

[image]

is there a way to wait until promisse has been resolved?, as you see I am already using async await on the function call.

Comment: `getNFTDetail` must return a promise; there's no other option. It's not possible to return a value that doesn't exist yet. To use the eventual value in the promise, either call `.then` on the promise and put your code in the callback, or put your code in an async function and `await` the promise. Since you appear to have an array of promises, `Promise.all` may be useful for you too to combine them into a single promise.

Comment: FYI if you're going to write functions like `async (url: any) =>` you might as well stop using TypeScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just, decide if you use *async / await* or *.then / .catch*:

```
const getNFTDetail = async (url: any) => {
  const urlIPF = url.replace("ipfs://", "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/");
  const { data } = await axios.get(urlIPF);
    return data;
};
```

or

```
const getNFTDetail = (url: any) => {
  const urlIPF = url.replace("ipfs://", "https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/");

  axios.get(urlIPF).then(({data}) => {
    // use your data here
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When you fetch a request, no matter any http client you use, will then return a Promise.

Just use `await` to get a response from your request.

```
const response = await axios.get(your-url);
const json = await response.json();
```

To use typescript correctly, type the url a string: `(url: string)` instead of happy `any` type.